# How to make a string compatible with Reader or InputStream types?

Tags: java

I am using Drools Planner which takes configuration by XML. The `configure` method is done this way (from the javadocs):

```
 XmlSolverConfigurer    configure(InputStream in)

 XmlSolverConfigurer    configure(Reader reader)

 XmlSolverConfigurer    configure(String resource)
```

The `configure(String resource)` takes a filename, not XML **contents**.

I want the `configure` method to accept **XML contents in a string object**. How do I make a string compatible with Reader or InputStream for the method to accept it?

---

For the curious: yes, I am doing things a bit convoluted to start with.

Comment: Note that's there's also a programmatic API, in can you prefer that :) See manual.

Comment: Did you trace me *in person*? :D But I got my (naive) reasons to express it in XML and parsing it. Thanks.

Comment: Nah, just the latest drools-planner links in google :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [`StringReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html).

Comment: Uh, I do this, right? StringReader sreader= new StringReader(String s)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this for input stream

```
InputStream u = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(file name);
```